# Check vector items and add to a new vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to vectors in C++, and after following a tutorial on vectors I have written my program as below:

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> regular;
  vector<int> large;
  int n;
  do{
    cout << "Enter a number : " ;
    cin >> n;
    regular.push_back(n); //add the number to the vector

  }while (n!=0);
  for(int i = 0; i<regular.size(); i++){
    // this is to test if each value is larger than x
    if(largevalues(regular[i]))
    {
      large.push_back(regular[i]);
      cout<< large[i] <<endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

however, the out for an input like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7` is not as expected. It will print some weird values.

if instead of

```
large.push_back(regular[i]);
cout<< large[i] <<endl;
```

I just do

```
cout<< regular[i] <<endl;
```

then it will print all numbers larger than x. Can someone explain why the `large.push_back(regular[i]);` does not add these values to a new vector?

Comment: Your program expects whitespace-separated integers on input, not comma-separated.

Comment: Assuming `largevalues` doesn't always return true, your `large` vector is shorter than `regular`. `i` may very well be a in range for the latter, but out of bounds for the former. Print `large.size()` to confirm.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, that was just a sample input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of `regular[i]`

are not necessarily the same as..

the contents of `large[i]` following the `push_back`

For example, if regular was of size 10, and large was size 1

then, you pushed back the 10th index of regular into large and tried to access `large[10]` ... you are going to have an index out of bounds problem

If you want to see the value of what you just pushed back, you could say something like `cout<< large.back() <<endl;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the same index for large and regular in the last loop. try:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<regular.size(); i++){
  // this is to test if each value is larger than x
  if(largevalues(regular[i]))
  {
    large.push_back(regular[i]);
    cout<< large[j++] <<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just answered the same thing dude

Comment: this did change the output but not to the correct output